# Peers counts by bootnode and non-boot node are different

Tags: ethereumjs, besu

I just setup a 4 nodes `Besu` network `21.1.5` on a single Ubuntu 20.04 server. The peer count on boot node is 4. However it is 3 peers on all other non-boot node. Is it right that the peer counts from boot node and non-boot node are different?

The following is the log from boot node :

```
2021-05-24 12:50:33.065+08:00 | pool-8-thread-1 | DEBUG | BaseBftController | New chain head detected (block number=106392), currently mining on top of 106391.
2021-05-24 12:50:34.862+08:00 | EthScheduler-Timer-0 | DEBUG | FullSyncTargetManager | Caught up to best peer: 106391, Peers: 4
2021-05-24 12:50:34.862+08:00 | EthScheduler-Timer-0 | DEBUG | WaitForPeerTask | Waiting for new peer connection. 4 peers currently connected.
2021-05-24 12:50:35.000+08:00 | pool-8-thread-1 | DEBUG | IbftRound | Creating proposed block. round=ConsensusRoundIdentifier{Sequence=106393, Round=0}
2021-05-24 12:50:35.024+08:00 | pool-8-thread-1 | DEBUG | IbftRound | Received a prepare message. round=ConsensusRoundIdentifier{Sequence=106393, Round=0}
```

Here is non-boot node log:

```
3ef461d284abfecb72be4a2cdaa6a271) in 0.000s. Peers: 3
2021-05-24 12:40:17.057+08:00 | EthScheduler-Workers-2 | INFO | PersistBlockTask | Imported
#106
,084 / 0 tx / 0 om / 0 (0.0%) gas / (0x2b91d68407a7d67dee2209fd3ee6af967ac49870be363117019929f070f326a3) in 0.000s. Peers: 3
2021-05-24 12:40:17.058+08:00 | pool-8-thread-1 | INFO | IbftBesuControllerBuilder | Produced
#106
,084 / 0 tx / 0 pending / 0 (0.0%) gas / (0x2b91d68407a7d67dee2209fd3ee6af967ac49870be363117019929f070f326a3)
2021-05-24 12:40:19.059+08:00 | pool-8-thread-1 | INFO | IbftBesuControllerBuilder | Imported
#106
,085 / 0 tx / 0 pending / 0 (0.0%) gas / (0x2c99e49ea401105514369d507c87f22d91efa2b2e94fdfdd5f31e1780d484d3a)
2021-05-24 12:40:19.059+08:00 | EthScheduler-Workers-0 | INFO | PersistBlockTask | Imported
#106
,085 / 0 tx / 0 om / 0 (0.0%) gas / (0x2c99e49ea401105514369d507c87f22d91efa2b2e94fdfdd5f31e1780d484d3a) in 0.000s. Peers: 3
```